# Removing headers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file, header, directory

I have thousands of folders with thousands of files that need to be programmed in MatLAB. These all have headers, which MatLAB cannot read. I've been trying to use the dlmread function, however, it seems as if it can only read individual files. Any suggestions? My files have a two line header.

My current code (not working for entire folders):

```
datadir='D:\Visitor\S\HA\Data\Folder1\2001' 
datadir1=dir(fullfile(datadir, 'ext*.txt')); EXT2001 = dlmread(datadir1,' ', 2, 0);
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not really understanding what your issue is, you've already specified a row offset with `dlmread` that will ignore the headers.

Comment: Similar question yes but that question does not have an accepted answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a structure of data from [`dir`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) to [`dlmread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html). That won't work. You have to loop over the files returned by `dir` and pass each to `dlmread` separately. You can store the output data in a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html), like so:

```
nFiles = numel(datadir1);
data = cell(1, nFiles);
for iFile = 1:nFiles
  filePath = fullfile(datadir1(iFile).folder, datadir1(iFile).name);
  data{iFile} = dlmread(filePath,' ', 2, 0);
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly! I upvoted but it's not showing up.

Comment: @S.Smith: You don't have enough [rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) to upvote yet, but you can mark it as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: It worked, but it is putting all of my data into a 1x4 cell. I can click on each element in the cell and it expands it, but is it possible to extract this into separate files?